# Executing MSSQL File from Python 3.9

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlite

I have a large SQL script which is too large to run from SQL Server Management Studio.

Is there a way to run such a script using Python?

SQLite3 doesn't seem to work. I keep getting syntax errors but the query is standard SQL.

Is there an MSSQL equivalent library in Python?

Comment: SQL Server is a completely different product from SQLite.

Comment: Microsoft encourages use of pyodbc. See the details here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you using `Microsoft SQL Server` or `SQLite` ?

Comment: What makes your script too large to run from SSMS? Does it run out of memory? Does it take too long to execute? (Which is subjective, because SSMS has no query timeout by default.) Or do you get some other error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cursor from a pyodbc connection.

```
cursor.execute(<sql code as string>)
cursor.commit()
```

If you use sqlalchemy, you can get the cursor from engine as follows:

```
engine.raw_connection().cursor()
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it working. I had to split each insert statement so I added a few tildes and used that.

`for statement in sql_file.read().split('~~~~'):`